# Typescript with Redux-Thunk giving error

Tags: angular, typescript, redux-thunk

I just took over an Angular 2/ Redux project in haste. I don't know Angular 2 very well, unfortunately. I'm trying to bootstrap the project with `npm start` but getting this error:

```
app/_dashboard.store.ts(54,37): error TS2345: Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any) => void'.
```

This is the code that's causing the error:

```
export const getNotificationAlerts: Function = () => {

let url = '/myaccount/GetUserProfileAlertSettings';

post(url, {}, true)
    .then(function (response) {
        DashboardStore.dispatch((dispatch) => {
            if (response.data) {
                let notifications = response.data;

                delete notifications.ResultCode;

                dispatch({
                    type: 'STORE_NOTIFICATIONS',
                    notifications: notifications
                });
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        DashboardStore.dispatch((dispatch) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'ERROR_STORE_NOTIFICATIONS',
                error: error
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'dashboard-notifications',
templateUrl: '../Templates/dashboard/notifications.html',
animations: [
    trigger('notificationVisibility', [
        state('true', style({ opacity: 1, display: 'block' })),
        state('false', style({ opacity: 0, display: 'none', height: '0px' })),
        transition('*=>*', animate('0.15s'))
    ])
]
})
export class DashboardNotificationsComponent {

// Initialize variables
@Input() data: any;
//showNotifications = 'true';
notificationActionSelected = false;

constructor() { }

processDetailsApproval: Function = (val, sender) => {

    let thisComponet = this;

    // Set disappear flag for class
    this.notificationActionSelected = true;

    if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
        processSenderApproval({
            'Status': val,
            'RecipientId': sender.RecipientId,
            'BusinessId': sender.BusinessId
        });

    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        thisComponet.notificationActionSelected = false;
    }, 500);

}
}
```

The Post function

```
export const post = (url: string, data: Object, includeToken) => {

    let params: Object = {};

    if (includeToken) {
        params = addToken({});
    }

    if (data) {
        params = Object.assign({}, params, data);
    }

    params = qs.stringify(params);

    return axios.post(url, params);

}
```

I've spent all day looking up solutions, but since I took over this project without much training, I'm very unsure about what I need to search for, even, and answers don't make sense to me. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: did you attach actions and component? Post full component code and how you are exporting it

Comment: @PriyeshKumar added the component code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

getNotificationAlerts function should return another function for redux-thunk. I did not work with ng2-redux but only with angular1 redux. Mabe this will work?

```
export const getNotificationAlerts: Function = () => {

   let url = '/myaccount/GetUserProfileAlertSettings';

   return post(url, {}, true)
   ...
 }
```